# get variables from routing if more than one hyphens presents

Tags: php, symfony

using symfony 3.0 where I want to get the ID from the URL.

```
  /**
   * @Route("/pathtocontent/{id}-{name}", defaults={"id"=null,"name"=null}, 
requirements={"name"="[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+", "id"="\d+"}, name="routingname")
   * @Route("/pathtocontent/{name}-{id}", defaults={"id"=null,"name"=null}, 
requirements={"name"="[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+", "id"="\d+"}, 
name="routingname_alias")
   */
  public function pathAction(Request $request, $id = null) {    
  }
```

So I have 2 rules for the same action. The URL can be:

> /pathtocontent/Name-part-comes-here-1234

and also could be like that:

> /pathtocontent/1234-Name-part-comes-here

The problem is the first case, where the name get all the:
**Name-part-comes-here-1234** value and the Id is **null**

How can I force the first case to parse the Id value out too, so I need to get the **Id** (1234) from the :

> /pathtocontent/Name-part-comes-here-1234

Comment: I don't think that `@Route("/pathtocontent/{name}-{id}"` is valid if your `name` contains hyphens. How should the transformer know the `id`?

Comment: this is what I would like to figure out

Comment: It's not possible, because within your `name` regex for route `{name}-{id}` the `id` will always be matched by the `name` regex, since you are allowing numbers `0-9`.  Therefore there is nothing left to parse anymore, hence id will be null.

Comment: The only way I can see to do it is to use /{nameid} and parse out the trailing -1234.  If you have a number of similar routes then you could use a listener to perform this transformation behind the scenes as it were.

Answer (score 0):

Use just:

```
@Route("/pathtocontent/{name}/{id}", defaults={"id"=null,"name"=null},
```

Because use have many `hyphens` (-)

Comment: I know. But must have a solutions I guess